# How to "cut" a tensor into half in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor with shape `[1, 2, 96, 96]` and would like two tensors with the shape `[1, 1, 96, 96]`, is there a quick way of doing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use indexing, i.e. `x[:, 0]` and `x[:, 1]`.

Answer (score 3):

`a, b = tensor.split(1, dim=1)` should do the job. By specifying 1 you specify how many elements should be in each split e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5,6].split(2) -> [1,2] [3,4] [5,6]`. Then `dim` just specifies which dimension to split over which in your case would be one.

EDIT:
if you wanted to cut it in half more generally use `tensor.split(n)` where `n` is half the size of the tensor. So in your specific case if you had shape `[1,10,96,96]` you would use `tensor.split(5,dim=1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to split a tensor into `n_chunks`, you'd better use `torch.chunk(n_chunks)`; see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.chunk.html

Instead, if you want to split a tensor into sub-tensors with a specific `size`(s), you can use `torch.split(size)`; see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.split.html